# Iterate Matcher Regex Java

Tags: java, regex, match

I would like given a input String, iterate every substring of this String that contain a pattern, then apply to these substrings another pattern, and replace that part in some way.
This is the code:

```
public static String parseLinkCell1NoLost(String cell) {

    String link = cell;
    Pattern catPattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = catPattern.matcher(cell);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        Pattern newP = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{nowrap|(.*?)\\}\\}", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = newP.matcher(cell);

        if (m.matches()) {
            String rest = m.group(0);
            String prov = m.group(1);
            String[] temp = prov.split("\\|");
            if (temp == null || temp.length == 0) {
                return link;
            } else {
                link = link.replace(rest, temp[1]);
            }
        }

    }
    return link;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot get the substring that matches every `matcher.find()`. So if I have like input `"{{nowrap|x}} {{nowrap|y}}"` I would like to iterate two times and get the substring `{{nowrap|x}}` in the first while, and `{{nowrap|y}}` in the second.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it is not good, I have to apply different pattern newP to every substring.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you are doing. The newP pattern contains a redundant `Pattern.MULTILINE` (you may remove it) and the unescaped `|` that creates an *alternation*. `\\{\\{nowrap|(.*?)\\}\\}` matches either `{{nowrap` or any 0+ chars other than linebreaks and then `}}`. Did you mean to escape the `|`? What is the output for `"{{nowrap|x}} {{nowrap|y}}"`?

Comment: Ok, I have first in the while check every substring with {{...}} and then inside the while check other regex, like {{nowrap|...}} or {{birthday|16|09|1991}}, and handle them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String parseLinkCell1NoLost(String cell) {
    String link = cell;
    Pattern catPattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = catPattern.matcher(cell);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        Pattern newP = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{nowrap\\|(.*?)\\}\\}", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = newP.matcher(matcher.group(0));

        if (m.matches()) {
            String rest = m.group(0);
            String prov = m.group(1);
            link = link.replace(rest, prov);
        }
    }
    return link;
}
```

Two small mistakes:

- in the loop you should use `matcher.group(0)` to only use your match not the whole cell in every iteration
- you need to escape the `|` symbol in a regex
- once that is corrected the `replace(..)` can be simpiflied as well